# create a column where each value is the result of an if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse

Hello I have a data frame where the 2nd and 3rd column have integers

```
head(mtcars)[,c(5,6)]

|drat |wt|
| ---|---|
|3.90|2.620|
|3.90|2.875|
|3.85|2.320|
|3.08|3.215|
|3.15|3.440|
|2.76|3.460|
```

The issue is that I want to add a third column in a way that in a row wise fashion, if the col2 number is greater to the col3 number, then the value on the same row will be "-". If the opposite is true (col2 is greater than col3), then the row value on the new column will be "+".

This is what I tried:

```
mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(strand = 
           if (drat < wt ){
             print("-"); else
               print("+")
           })
```

but I got error message:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "           }"

Expected output:

```
|drat|wt|strand|
|----|--|------|
|3.90|2.620|"-"|
|3.90|2.875|"-"|
|3.85|2.320|"-"|
|3.08|3.215|"+"|
|3.15|3.440|"+"|
|2.76|3.460|"+"|
```

Comment: do you need: `mutate(strand = ifelse(drat < wt, "-", "+"))`?

Comment: If is not vectorized

Comment: … and you are missing both an opening and closing brace (`{` and `}`) on either side of your `else`. And as others have pointed out, `rowwise()` is unnecessary if you use `ifelse`.

Comment: and not sure what a semi colon is doing there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace semicolon ";" with "}".
and for else open a new "{"
here is your code it works well:

```
mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(strand = 
           if (drat < wt ){
             print("-")} else{
               print("+")
           })
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `{}` and `;`:

```
head(mtcars)[,c(5,6)] %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(strand = if (drat < wt )print("-") else print("+"))
```

```
   drat    wt strand
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1  3.9   2.62 +     
2  3.9   2.88 +     
3  3.85  2.32 +     
4  3.08  3.22 -     
5  3.15  3.44 -     
6  2.76  3.46 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ifelse might be easiest:

```
mtcars$strand <- ifelse(test = mtcars$drat < mtcars$wt, 
                        yes = "+", 
                        no = "-")

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb strand
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      -
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      -
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      -
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      +
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      +
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      +
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this suits you:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(strand = ifelse (drat < wt, '-', '+'))
```